# How to block external access to website?

Tags: web, block, offline

I'm currently building a web server on Centos7 and I'm using Virtualmin and Nginx instead of Apache.I have established the connections and I'm now going to install some modules and later install Wordpress. But how can I set the site to 'offline mode' or make it only accessible internally so that google and others can't reach the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to generate .htpasswd file